# selector for cloned table? table2excel

Tags: jquery

i am using [this library](https://github.com/JackGit/table2excel.js) to convert a table to excel. This works great.

This is my table

```
<table id="tab"><tr><td>100 Hours</td><td>John</td></tr><tr><td>120 Hours</td><td>Anny</td></tr></table>
```

This is my script:

```
function export_exceljs(){                        
  new Table2Excel('#tab').export();
}
```

But now i like to clone the table, remove the Word "Hours" and create a Excel file. But i dont like to modify the website. So i like to clone the table, modify the clone and create the file from the clone. But i dont know how send the clone to the table2excel function?

```
function export_exceljs(){
   var cln = $('#tab').clone();
   cln.find('td').each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Hours', '').trim())
   })
   cln.find('.noExl').remove();
   new Table2Excel(cln ???? ).export();
}
```

Comment: Since `Table2Excel()` expects a selector insert clone in DOM with new id and remove it after export

Comment: Can i insert it in hidden mode? Or can i hide it? The user should not be penetrated with this. Maybe you can give me a sample?

Comment: My guess would be yes so long as that exporter doesn't need any dimensions. Elements can also be positioned absolute and far off screen if needed. Eiher way user would not see anything

Comment: Do you have an example code to add the clone to DOM an hide it?

Comment: `cln.attr('id','newId').hide(); $('body').append(cln)`

Comment: Thanks man i give it a try